# php array access from response data

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist

I have project ongoing and need a help in array from api server
I get 2 type of data response

1st one

```
{"STATUS":"OK","MESSAGE":"","DATA":{"DETAILS": "BLUE","BOUGHT_PRODUCTS":["1071026"]}}
```

2nd one is

```
{"STATUS":"OK","MESSAGE":"","DATA":{"DETAILS": "GREEN","ACTIVE_PRODUCTS":{"151941":{"price":"4.00","no_check_price":"3.20"}}}}
```

3rd one is

```
{"STATUS":"ERROR","MESSAGE":"No products found!"}
```

My problem is if response data message  No products found! then cart product id will be remove from cart table
and else data response content        "BOUGHT_PRODUCTS": [ "1071026"]
array . bought_product id will be delete from cart and product table.

also  if response have    "ACTIVE_PRODUCTS" then checkout should be continue.

i need just bought and not found help to delete id from cart ?
i tried but i cant cause it response sometime active_product somtime bought product.

you guys are expert i m newbi . help

```
actully when user click checkout . then foreach id from cart it hit in api url to check product is available to buy or not

if (count($totalcart) > 0) {
            $x = $this->api->getProductsPrice($id);
            file_put_contents(storage_path() . "/productprice.txt", json_encode($x), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            if ($x['STATUS'] == 'ERROR' && preg_match("/No products/", $x['MESSAGE'])) {
                Product::whereIn('id', $id)->delete();
                Cart::whereIn('product_id', $id)->delete();
            } else {
                //$active = $x['DATA']['ACTIVE_PRODUCTS'];
            }
        }
```

here is my code. i need just the elseif /else condition 
if $x['DATA']['BOUGHT_PRODUCTS'] then it will remove the product from user cart also from DB
or

Comment: Hi Khan! I know English can be a problem, but a simple "please" surely would not hurt and make your request sound less like a command. Furthermore: how should we find out what's going on without any code? Even the best expert is not a mind reader, and I am pretty sure the crystal ball will fail, too. Please show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: now i added please check

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg i update the post please check

Comment: I was just reviewing the question. I have no idea about PHP, sorry.